# Why is my swap method interfering with make_move_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, move-semantics

This one has me thoroughly confused. In the below sample I get the error:

> error C2664: 'void std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::swap(std::unique_ptr<_Ty>
>   &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' to
>   'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&'

I have no idea whatsoever how it's ending up at my swap function, or why it's a problem. <strike>Interestingly if I change the signature of `void swap(const one& other)` and remove the const to `void swap(one& other)` everything works.</strike> if I change the signature of `void swap(const one& other)` and remove the const to `void swap(one& other)` it compiles in VS2010 but is still broken in GCC. If there are no swap overloads there is no problem.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class one
{
public:
    one(){}
    one(one&& other) : x(std::move(other.x)) {}
    one& operator=(one&& other){ x = std::move(other.x); return *this; }

    void swap(const one& other){ x.swap(other.x); }
    void swap(one&& other){ x.swap(std::move(other.x)); }

private:
    one(const one&);
    one& operator=(const one&);

    std::unique_ptr<int> x;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void swap(one& left, one& right)
{
    left.swap(right);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void swap(one&& left, one& right)
{
    right.swap(std::move(left));
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void swap(one& left, one&& right)
{
    left.swap(std::move(right));
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class two
{
public:
    two(){}
    two(two&&){}
    two& operator=(two&&){ return *this; }

    operator one(){return one();}

private:
    two(const two&);
    two& operator=(const two&);
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    std::vector<two> twos(10);
    std::vector<one> ones(std::make_move_iterator(twos.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(twos.end()));
}
```

**Edit:**
The non-constness requirement makes sense. Entirely an oversight on my part. Why is it calling swap in the first place though?

(For reference, I'm using VS2010)

[Demo of it broken](http://ideone.com/DIJiqE)

[Demo of it still broken, but this 'fix' works in VS2010](http://ideone.com/lEdGV1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// other can't be const since swap modifies it
void swap(one& other){ x.swap(other.x); }

// Why swapping? (swap on rvalues don't work either since it's pointless.)
//Just move the other
void swap(one&& other){ x = std::move(other.x); }
```

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/aZHWQQ) works on my GCC, maybe it's just a bug on older GCCs.

Comment: The difference is that ipc didn't replace the swap with = in the implementation of swap(one&&).

Answer (score 2):

The full error message is as follows (I've introduced some newlines to prevent horizontal scrolling):

> ```
> error C2664: 'void std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::swap(std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&)'
>     : cannot convert parameter 1
>         from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
>         to 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty> &&'
> with
> [
>     _Ty=int
> ]
> Conversion loses qualifiers
> ```

The error occurs on the following line of your code:

```
void swap(const one& other){ x.swap(other.x); }
```

`other` is const-qualified, but `std::unique_ptr::swap` requires a non-const argument.  Thus, the "conversion loses qualifiers" (specifically, the const qualifier).

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty much straightforward to me. When you swap two objects, none of them could be read-only. They both should be modifiable, only then swap can be done.

So your `swap` function must take non-const reference.

Note that `std::unique_ptr<T>` doesn't have `swap` function which takes *rvalue* reference. In fact, it doesn't even make much sense to have one. VS2010 is non-standard in that regard. The Standard (§20.7.1.2) requires just one with this signature:

```
void swap(std::unique_ptr<T> &) noexcept;
```

There is no `swap` for rvalue-reference. I would also suggest you to remove your swap that takes rvalue-reference. It adds unnecessary complexity to your code.

Comment: That was entirely an oversight on my part heh. I feel dumb. In any case, who is calling swap? And why is it still broken [here](http://ideone.com/lEdGV1)? EDIT: It appears VS2010 has an overload for a non-rvalue-ref swap and GCC doesn't.

Comment: @Dave: `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have `swap` function which takes rvalue reference. In fact, it doesn't even make much sense to have one!

Comment: Ugh, I'm failing at basic thought today.

Comment: @Dave: VS2010 is non-standard in that regard. The standard requires just one `std::unique_ptr<T>::swap(std::unique_ptr<T> &) noexcept`. There is no rvalue-reference.

Comment: Why is swap being called? I will take your advice and get rid of the rvalue overload

Comment: @Dave: It is not *actually* called in your code in `main()`, but it is called in the definition of the class itself, that can be referred to as "swap being called" right? The compiler has to make sure that the code is syntactically correct. It is like this `void f() { int a = "hello"; }` Now this will give error, even if you don't call this function. Simple, isn't?

Comment: Note that some drafts of C++0x had rvalue-reference overloads for swap, although they were later removed.